# Nicely columned printing of a list in Python with variable length strings and numbers

Tags: python-3.x

I want to print a bunch of these so that they form nicely columned output but due to the word lengths varying they don't match up. So how can I do it. Currently I am doing this:

```
print (*self.animal, sep='\t') # the output is from printing this 4 times with varying data in self.animal


herbivore       intermittent    0       walker  0       24000   12      6
herbivore       filter  0       walker  0       24000   12      6
carnivore       siren   0       walker  0       24000   12      6
event   rain    4       walker  0       24000   12      6
```

I tried formatting codes but then the *self.animal gives an error.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`tabulate`](https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/):

```
from tabulate import tabulate

lst1 = ["cat", "crocodile", "horse", "cow", "wolf"]
lst2 = ["apple", "orange", "banana", "pineapple", "strawberry"]
lst3 = [0, 11, 17, 1675625315, 13]

print(tabulate([lst1, lst2, lst3], tablefmt="plain"))
```

which prints the expected output:

```
cat    crocodile  horse   cow         wolf
apple  orange     banana  pineapple   strawberry
0      11         17      1675625315  13
```